# Why does an h1 tag inside a body tag pushes the body tag down, resulting in a scrollbar showing up?

Tags: html, css

Why in this snipped the scrollbar shows up?

I see that body is 100% tall as indicated by CSS, but it is not positioned at the top of the page. Instead, the margin from the `h1` tag is pushing `body` down by that amount, resulting in the scrollbar because the `body` does not fit in the page.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

My question is.. if the margin is in the `h1` tag and `h1` is inside `body`, why does `body` get pushed down and the scrollbar shows up?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: The thing is margin of H1 element is not "inside" the BODY but "hangs" above it.  See margin collapsing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: Ah, yes.. I usually don't hit that issue because the first element on a page doesn't usually have margins. Forgot about collapsing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. set margin on h1 to 0
2. set overflow to hidden on body
3. remove height:100% from body and html

The snippet below does all three but any 1 will work

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
 
 

.root {
  height: 100%;
}

h1{margin:0;}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works the same if you delete `height: 100%;`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Use the `margin` to position the `H1` element.

Most programmers use the CSS `*` Selector.

- The * selector selects all elements.
- The * selector can also select all elements inside another element.
- Read more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage).

Example:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
*{
  margin: 0;
}
.root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

In this case, all elements will have a `margin: 0;`
It will work even if you leave `height: 100%;` the `html` and `body`.

And the last option, just like above, write a `margin: 0;` for each element.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```